# Data storage problem/question in decentralised private blockchain that i am going to build

Tags: python, blockchain, distributed

I am trying to build a private blockchain with python, the amount of nodes that will be connecting to the network is not going to be a large number since it is private. The problem is that, will all the transactions in the blockchain lose if all the nodes in the network are offline? And how should i solve it if all the transactions will lose?

Comment: I think the bigger question is why do you want to use blockchain in a private network? Also, the answer is yes, data becomes unavailable if the system is down, that is not unique to blockchain, or distributed networks for that matter.

Comment: @JBaczuk because I'm trying to build a permissioned Blockchain that is not open to anyone, I want to store some important and private transaction into the Blockchain, so I don't want it to be open to the public

Comment: Why not just have a central server store the state of the network, why do you need blockchain? Blockchain is not a database, it is for achieving distributed consensus in a permission-less (public) network.

Comment: @JBaczuk I want the immutability of Blockchain.... And I just need to record every transaction has been done

Comment: Blockchain is only immutable if a majority of the participants choose not to modify the data (see 51% attack). With a permissioned network, participants are controlled by the central authority anyway, so you might as well just store it in a database on the central server, it will be much more efficient.

Comment: What @JBaczuk saying is right. If someone is running a private blockchain, they can control everything. Might as well can edit the previous block too. So immutability is easily lost when it's private & controlled.